# Boost X3 parse struct with containers

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I trying to parse the following strings like the following:

```
pc_us_ru_2_ua_3_inet(evdev)_capslock(grouplock)
```

Into the following struct:

```cpp
struct LayoutSymbols
{
    std::vector<std::string> layouts; // Will contain {us,ru,ua} for example above
    std::vector<std::string> options; // Will contain {inet(evdev), capslock(grouplock)} for example above
};


BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(LayoutSymbols,
    layouts, options
)
```

Here is my code:

```cpp
std::string test = "pc_us_ru_2_ua_3_inet(evdev)_capslock(grouplock)";
LayoutSymbols layoutSymbols;
x3::phrase_parse(test.begin(), test.end(), "pc_" >> (+x3::char_("a-z") >> -('_' >> +x3::char_("a-z") >> '_' >> x3::omit[x3::alnum]))
                 >> '_' >> (+x3::char_("a-z") >> x3::char_('(') >> +x3::char_("a-z") >> x3::char_(')')) % '_',
        x3::space, layoutSymbols);
```

But I have compilation error:

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/operator/detail/sequence.hpp:148: error: static assertion failed: Size of the passed attribute is less than expected.
  148 |             actual_size >= expected_size
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is it possible to specify `>>` for the following:
`+x3::char_("a-z") >> '_' >> -(+x3::char_("a-z") >> '_' >> x3::alnum` to read any element into a vector of `LayoutSymbols` instead of reading into it members?

Comment: The `phrase_parse` doesn't seem to be parsing the `_3_inet` part of the `test` string.

Comment: @cigien, thanks, it was a typo. But the question still the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using rules:

```cpp
namespace LayoutSymbolsParser
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    x3::rule<class SymbolsRule, LayoutSymbols> const symbolsRule = "symbols";
    x3::rule<class LayoutsRule, std::vector<std::string>> const layoutsRule = "layouts";
    x3::rule<class OptionsRule, std::vector<std::string>> const optionsRule = "options";

    const auto symbolsRule_def = "pc_" >> layoutsRule >> -('_' >> optionsRule);
    const auto layoutsRule_def = +x3::alpha >> *('_' >> +x3::alpha >> '_' >> x3::omit[x3::digit]);
    const auto optionsRule_def = x3::lexeme[+(x3::char_ - ')') >> x3::char_(')')] % '_';

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(symbolsRule, layoutsRule, optionsRule);
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
std::string test = "pc_us_ru_2_ua_3_inet(evdev)_capslock(grouplock)";
LayoutSymbols layoutSymbols;
x3::phrase_parse(test.begin(), test.end(), LayoutSymbolsParser::symbolsRule, x3::space, layoutSymbols);
```